# Selenium function selectFrame not working in Xebium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, fitnesse

I recieved the following error when trying to type in an input field during a Xebium test:

`Element belongs to a different frme than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it`

So I tried using the selectFrame command:

```
| do | selectFrame | on | id=iframe0 |
```

I received the error:

```
Unable to locate frame: id=iframe0
```

My test runs in Selenium IDE (with and without the selectFrame command) with no errors. I tried using different locators with no improvement in Xebium. Am I doing something wrong? Is this Xebium's problem? What other method can I use for getting to the correct frame to enter my data?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but discovered that it works when running the tests using Selenium RC instead of WebDriver.

I think the problem isn't Xebium itself. It's more of a problem with the selectFrame() method when using the Selenium->WebDriver compatibility mode.

Anyway, if you start your own WebDriver-Server instance (Selenium RC is included in it) and set your Xebium test to point to it, using iFrames should work.

Comment: How do i set the xebium test to point to a selenium RC instance?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

The first time i used selectFrame in my test worked, but when i needed to switch to another frame it failed.
 
I had recorded my test in Selenium IDE and playback in IDE worked fine, but using the Xebium formatter and then playing the same test from Xebium it failed.

The Xebium formatter gave me this:

```
| do | selectFrame | on | tabs |
| ensure | do | click | on | link=Form |
| do | selectFrame | on | relative=up |
| do | selectFrame | on | menu |
```

So the selectFrame on frame "tabs" worked, but the selectFrame on "menu" did not.

As you notice, in between the 2 is the selectFrame on relative=up. This line was actually where my test got an exception in the "output captured" page and in the testpage itself it seemed the 2 selectFrame commands were skipped.

It seems before selecting another frame, the webdriver needs to go back to the default frame, which is why the relative=up is there.

Then i changed the command to this:

```
| do | selectFrame | on | relative=top |
```

And all worked like a charm. It seems the relative=up is not working correct, but the relative=top does work (for me anyway). hope this works for you too.